# Is there any stable way in selenium to select 1000+ rows

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have list of 1200 rows in one page , I am selecting rows based on some condition. Mostly my condition occurs true 1000 times so selenium trying to select 1000 rows one by one but some time it select 500, some time 800, some time 1000. Is there any way to make it stable?

When I check my condition , it always has correct size to select rows. But selenium not able to work in same way all time.

Code :

```
        public static List<String> listOfData;
        public static int x=0;

driver.get(URL);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Xpath1)));


           List<WebElement> TRcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

           System.out.println(TRcount.size());
           List<WebElement> TDcount = null;

           if(TRcount.size()>0)
           {
               for(int i=2;i<TRcount.size();i++)
               {


                  listOfData = new ArrayList<String>();
                  TDcount = TRcount.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

                  for(int j=0; j<TDcount.size(); j++) 
                  {

                      if(TDcount.get(j).getText().equals("Loading..."))
                      {
                          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                      }


                        listOfData.add(TDcount.get(j).getText());

                  }      
                        if(TDcount.size()>0)
                          {


                              if(GlobalMethods.checkIfDataExists((listOfData)))
                                  {
                                       listOfTrueId.add(i);
                                       x++;
                                  }
                        }


               }      

           int count=2;
           for(int k = 0; k <= listOfTrueId.size(); k++)
           {

                Thread.sleep(3000);
                TRcount.get(count).click();
                //System.out.println(TDcount.get(0).getText() +" : "+ "Pass"); 
                //TDcount.get(0).click();
                 count++;


           }   



    }
```

Here **listOfTrueId** is my array which stores just no. of ids to get all rows to be selected. So mostly I get it's size near by 1000 which is correct.

**TRCount** is always correct. Issue is when it check for condition for data exist and do ++ in **listOfTrueId**

**TRcount** is also list element and help me to count TR from 1 to

But when it looping to select rows, It stops any time. As I understand my browser it shows 12 rows at a time and from next selenium automatic scrolling down one by one but then it stops at any row.

> **UPDATE :**

I just got to know that issue is TD tags data loading , When in starting it loads data it has text called **"Loading..."** , So my script getting this **"Loading..."** as value of TD and based on it selects less rows. So how can I tell to my script that if value of TD is **"Loading..."** then wait for a while and again check for same TD to get actual data.

I have put implicit wait in above script but that seems not helpful.

Comment: Why the `sleep` and why the `count`? `count=k` so that can just be k. Also this for loop does not really tell what is happening.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen - Let me share full script.

Comment: Keep it to the point which is relevant :)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen - Yeah , Just updated relevant code.

Comment: Why `i=2` and `count=2`? And the reason for failure might be that not every `TR` has `TD` resulting in `TRcount.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));` to return null. Can you test that?

Comment: Actually First 2 elements of table is Table Header so I set i=2 to get data from first actual TR. It is returning TD and TD counts and data properly. Can you please check as I UPDATE question. Issue is with data **loading only** :(. that I feel.

Comment: Just an idea: Replace the loading with a listener instead. Then you are not dependent on time outs which can be tricky (as you notice). Also the i=2: Your counter needs to be decreased by 2 then: `count+listOfTrueId.size()=2` rows beyond the nd of your table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99550/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-norbert-van-nobelen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` you don't actually doing any waiting, you are just setting the time the driver will try to find element in `driver.findElement`.

Try to change

```
if(TDcount.get(j).getText().equals("Loading..."))
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

To one of those:

- If you have locator

  ```
  //Explicit wait
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(By locator, "Loading..."));
  ```
- If the text is changing to the same text in all the elements

  ```
  //Explicit wait
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(TDcount.get(j), someText));
  ```
- Or just wait in loop

  ```
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 < 30 && TDcount.get(j).getText().equals("Loading..."));
  ```